# Google Sheets IMPORTDATA timeout

Tags: google-sheets, timeout, google-sheets-formula

**Does Google Sheets have a timeout associated with it's `IMPORTDATA` function?**

I assume it does, but there's nothing confirming this behavior in [the documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en). If anyone has measured this or found the docummentation somewhere, please share it! In the meantime I'll try and take some measurements myself.

---

For clarity, there are many questions and resources here on timeouts with scripts and the Sheets API.

Answer (score 1):

I have around 50+ google sheets that use the `IMPORTDATA` function in a cell to fetch info from one server in AWS that I operate. Since December 7 2020 I was getting "N/A"s. I changed the URL by adding a random parameter to skip the google cache and it would reload the data fine but in the next refresh cicle (takes like an hour) it would again return "N/A" in my sheets.

As an alternative I was trying something in Google Apps Script and when I fetched the URL with apps script code I would get an "Unexpected error" sometimes when I was fetching with the UrlFetchApp.fetch function, I could see in the logs in my own server a "200 - OK" response to the request from Google but still the sheet would show "N/A".

Finally, on my own server I actually enabled [gzipping the content through PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php) and I'm not getting any more "N/A"s so for sure there is some kind of timeout that by gzipping the content consumed by IMPORTDATA that I was able to go back into the IMPORTDATA threshold, whichever that is.